# Location trigger doesn't enable local notification on real device, only on simulator

Tags: swift, notifications, location, geofencing, unusernotificationcenter

I am implementing simple app which adds hardcoded local notification so Notification Center with location triggers. I have used this tutorial https://github.com/jgsamudio/LocationNotifier to implement it. However, notification shows on simulator, but not on real device.

#### I simulate location for simulator like this:

**Features -> Location -> Current Location** (I change location to exit and enter the desired region)

**Result:** notifications are pending and **I see** them in moment of entering/existing region.

#### For device:

**Debug -> Simulate Location -> London, England** (I change location to other or add custom one to exit and enter the desired region)

**Result:** notifications are pending and **I can't see** them in moment of entering/existing region.

Is there anyone who faced this problem? How did you solve it?

#### I have tried:

1. Using different iOS: 15.6, 16.4, 16.5 (Xcode 14.3.1)
2. Walking with pending notifications on my device along the street to trigger them
3. UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger works fine for all app states and both simulator and device. I can potentially schedule time notification when water a region in `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {...}` but it seems like a dirty hack
4. This tutorial https://www.kodeco.com/20690666-location-notifications-with-unlocationnotificationtrigger also leads to same behaviour (doesn't show notifications on device)

#### Desireed result:

See notifications triggered by `UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: <CLRegion>, repeats: <Bool>)` on my device